# How to change environment variable in Ubuntu 19.04 using its terminal

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-19.04

I tried below code in multiple time but can not get environment variable panel in Ubuntu 19.04.x

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment.
```

If anyone know how to do that, please help.

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc mention](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables), you should modify/add environment variables into the `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` (global envs) files or `.profile` (session envs) file.

Simply do the following as an example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```